# XML Serialization Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm trying to serialize my `ObservableCollection<Memos>` in an `XML` file.

The `Memos` class is like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Memos
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Event { get; set; }

    public BitmapImage Photo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public Memos() { }

    public static async Task<BitmapImage> LoadImage(StorageFile file)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

If I leave the `Photo` field, it works properly. But I don't understand why, because I don't mark it with the `[DataMember]` attribute.

My code goes like this:

```
using (var file = storage.CreateFile("Memos.xml"))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Memos>));
    serializer.Serialize(file, MainPage.ListMemos);
}
```

Comment: I don't think Photo property is reason of your serialize prob. it's not give you any prob in Serialize check proper I think you are making other mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to mark the property with `XmlIgnore` to prevent it from being serialized :

```
[XmlIgnore]
public BitmapImage Photo { get; set; }
```

Comment: @DhavalPatel complex type like `BitmapImage` has small chance to be serializable fine, and all public properties are included in serialization, that's why we need `XmlIgnore` attribute

Comment: Ohh Thanks for putting light on that I have no idea about it